# Working with threads in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, windows-services

Question? I have a win service that every minutes executes a method, sample code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            //Elapsed event
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

            timer.Interval = 60000;

            //enable timer
            timer.Enabled = true;

        }

protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }

 private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            timer.Enabled = false;

            SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT();

            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
```

OK, now the method SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT(); is a method that collects data from database and sends it to a client, I have to have a second method PROCESS_DATA(); a method that process data before sending it to the client, but the problem is that those both methods  work simultaneously on same tables in database so I don't want to get database lock or some other database error and with timers is a chance that methods get into a collision, one method processes data and the other one sends that data to client, but they have to work simultaneously and also separately, is there a way to do this kind of thing with threads and how?

Comment: Please change your sentence that runs over seven lines into a step by step description of what your code does, what you want it to do and what you tried to do to make it do that.

Comment: The code in methods is irrelevant, what I want to do is to run simultaneously methods mentioned previously, not with timer but with a thread, that all

Comment: I'm not talking about your code but about the explanation of your question, which is a bit unclear and unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea of how to get rid of your problem may be a double buffered threading loop.
This is a nice concept for implementing a game loop, but it may be also satisfy your needs.

You will have one thread that executes the PROCESS_DATA in an endless loop and another thread that executes SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT in an endless loop. And you have two buffers. This can be any kind of class or a structure holding the information returned by the PROCESS_DATA method.

The SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT loop is at first locked until the buffer_1 one is filled by the PROCESS_DATA thread. Then the PROCESS_DATA releases the lock on SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT and swaps the buffers. Now SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT owns the filled buffer and does with the data whatever it wants. While this is going on, the PROCESS_DATA simultaneously processes the next data and waits for either the SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT to finish or unlocks the SEND_DATA_TO_CLIENT to swap the buffers.

I hope you understand what I mean. If not, I can provide you with a picture.

```
/// <summary>
/// Author: Samuel Egger
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    private static EventWaitHandle swappedWh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

    private static object lockerA = new object();
    private static object lockerB = new object();

    private static int counter = 0;

    // The queues can be of any type which holds your data e.g. a struct or a class
    private static Queue<string> dataQueueA = new Queue<string>();
    private static Queue<string> dataQueueB = new Queue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread sendDataToClientThread = new Thread(SendDataToClient);
        Thread processDataThread = new Thread(ProcessData);

        sendDataToClientThread.IsBackground = false;

        processDataThread.Start();
        sendDataToClientThread.Start();
    }

    private static void ProcessData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockerA)
            {
                // Your time consuming process goes here. The result then must
                // must be saved (e.g. state) and then enqueued
                dataQueueA.Enqueue(state);
            }

            // If the operations result is equal to 2, then the render thread is done
            // and is waitung for getting unblocked
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 2)
            {
                counter = 0;
                SwapQueues();
                swappedWh.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                swappedWh.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SendDataToClient()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (lockerB)
            {
                // Send the data generated by the process data thread
                while (dataQueueB.Count > 0)
                {
                    string data = dataQueueB.Dequeue();
                    // Your process of sending the data goes here
                }
            }

            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 2)
            {
                counter = 0;
                SwapQueues();
                swappedWh.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                swappedWh.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }

    static void SwapQueues()
    {
        // Wait until both threads are "done" before swapping

        lock (lockerA)
        {
            lock (lockerB)
            {
                Queue<string> tmpQueue = dataQueueA;
                dataQueueA = dataQueueB;
                dataQueueB = tmpQueue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this little tricky example will help you.

Comment: Nice work Sam,that's is what I need, can you write some code how to do this

Comment: I can write you some code at the evening if you want. At the moment I am at work and do not have too much time for this.

Comment: No problem, there is no rush, I have time, thank you very much Sam!

Comment: So, I have added you the code example. Please let me know whether it helped your needs.

Comment: Many thanks, this is some nice work!!!

Comment: Hey Sam, the code is working fine, I make some adjustments to code because it has to work like win service, I have a question about a piece of code:Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1000)); and  Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 2), my methods sending and receiving are executing quite a long time so this number have to be bigger, but when a change them let say in rnd.next(30000) and ref counter == 4 the threads go mad, what number sholud I put here?

Comment: The Thread.Sleep was actually only for demonstration purpose. It will make completely no sense to keep this in your win service. So just remove it. You also do not need the Random instance which is also for the demonstration of my example. The counter is for controlling the thread "synchronisation". So don't change the if condition. This must always be 2.

Comment: I have updated the code example =)

Comment: One more thing, when I stop win service, I need to stop the thread, is it right to make processDataThread.Abort(); to stop the thread or somethig else can be done to stop the thread?

Comment: I'd rather recommend you to use a boolean variable for both the while loops instead of a constant true. Instead of calling Abort on the threads, set thîs variable to false and call Join on both of the threads. This will ensure that non of them gets interrupted unexpectedly. Maybe you will also need some additional logic. I think its important that you know what the code actually does. Make sure you know what lock means, or interlocked and so on =)